# What is the recommended alternative to kubectl '--generator' option?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

One of the points in the `kubectl` [best practices section in Kubernetes Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/#best-practices) state below:

> Pin to a specific generator version, such as `kubectl run
>   --generator=deployment/v1beta1`

But then a little down in the doc, we get to learn that except for Pod, the use of `--generator` option is deprecated and that it would be removed in future versions.

Why is this being done? Doesn't generator make life easier in creating a template file for resource definition of deployment, service, and other resources? What alternative is the kubernetes team suggesting? This isn't there in the docs :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kubectl create` is the recommended alternative if you want to use more than just a pod (like deployment).

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/#generators says:

> Note: `kubectl run --generator` except for `run-pod/v1` is deprecated in v1.12.

[This pull](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/68132) request has the reason why generators (except `run-pod/v1`) were deprecated:

> The direction is that we want to move away from `kubectl run` because it's over bloated and complicated for both users and developers. We want to mimic `docker run` with `kubectl run` so that it *only* creates a pod, and if you're interested in other resources `kubectl create` is the intended replacement.

Answer (score 1):

For deployment you can try

```
kubectl create deployment hello-node --image=gcr.io/hello-minikube-zero-install/hello-node
```

and

**Note**: `kubectl run --generator except for run-pod/v1` is deprecated in v1.12.

Comment: That precisely is my question, given that it is deprecated what is the recommended alternative that the Kubernates Doc is silent about?